# Запрос php

Tags: php, html

Почему начиная со [строки 4](http://codepad.org/tcHRFnTe)

```
$auth = "Привет ".$_SESSION['user']."!<br />\n";
```

php код на странице отображается как текст?

Comment: Что такое PHP запрос?

Comment: PHP скрипт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Stepan](/users/9171/stepan) Kurennyh вот вы привели ссылку на то, что выводится в у вас в результате выполнения. Прочитайте ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО какую ошибку выдает?

```
Warning: session_start(): open(/tmp/sess_3571b97393bf0a6e1f753d1a1eff0960, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory
```

это значит, что у вас либо нет прав на запись в эту директорию либо нет такой директории либо возможно пхп както не правильно настроен для работы с сессиями.

зыж и да, используйте `<?php` в начале строки, возможно в настройках short_tags запрещены.

Comment: @thunder - это я код свернул в codepad.org. Там использование сессий видимо запрещено

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте, я предполагаю, что причина в `<?`. Это `<?` замените на это `<?php`. P.S у вас три замены должно быть.

Comment: Так же правильно 1ая на `<?php`, 2я и 3я `<?=..`

Comment: @stck, на некоторых хостингах отключено короткие формы вывода. Такие как `<?=` или `<?php=` - не дадут того что мы ожидаем. Также `<?` начнет странно работать, в начале выполнять код ( 1 условие), а после выводит код как текст. Математические значения работают (++, =+...)

Comment: @Node_pro, <?= - не является короткой формой. Точнее является, но глотается.

Comment: замена <? на <?php ничего не меняет.

Comment: Попробуйте сохранять файлы без BOM

Answer (score 0):

Проверил код у себя - всё нормально. А каким образом вы открываете файл? Просто такое может возникнуть если вы к файлу напрямую обратились. Покажите пожалуйста что у вас в адресной строке.

Comment: В адресной строке http://адрес/ , т.е. файл открываю не напрямую

Comment: А какой веб-сервер используете? Возможно не настроен php-интерпретатор?

Comment: На windows стоит денвер, на ubuntu - apache+php результат один и тот же.

Comment: **1.** Возможно у ПШП не хватает привилегий для записи в папку `/tmp/` или такой папки не существует.  
**2.** Сами задайте в php.ini session.save_path для заведомо существующей открытой для записи/чтения папки.  
Попробуйте так.

Comment: Не помогает